# How to read JSONP by Spring rest template or jackson

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jackson, jsonp

I need to read some data from third party service. The last one provides only endpoint with callback (JSONP) to be used from javascript. But my task is read it from java side.

Sure I can get the string from third party side and remove callback call without any additional libraries or something like that to get exactly JSON, but firstly I want to check whether the spring rest template or jackson has such solution?

Answer (score 0):

Since JSONP content is not (necessarily) valid JSON, nor reliable definition of how inclusion should work, Jackson has no functionality for trying to decode it. You may want to use simple regexp to preprocess it, before handling it to Jackson for databinding.

I don't know if Spring might have something to help.